# When did a mother giving birth become the deliverer instead of the deliveree?

Tags: meaning, historical-change

*Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, Eleventh Edition (2003), gives meaning 3 of *deliver* as follows:

> **3 a** (1) **:** to assist in giving birth (2) **:** to aid in the birth of **b :** to give birth to **c :** to cause (oneself) to produce as if by giving birth

Definition 3b appears to be by far the most common birth-related meaning today, to judge from a [Google Books search of publications from the year 2000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22delivered%20a%20healthy%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) using the phrase "delivered a healthy." In 28 of the first 30 matches involving babies, the mother is named as the deliverer. (In the other two, credit goes, respectively, to "Jim and Bob" and to "the Lord"; in two additional instances, a company delivered "a healthy profit" or "a healthy 6.8% return.")

But in Samuel Johnson's [*Dictionary of the English Language*](http://www.archive.org/stream/dictionaryofengl01john#page/n277/mode/2up) (1756), the only birth-related definition of *deliver* is this one:

> 6 To disburden a woman of a child.

And a book by Jacques Guillemeau, translated in 1635 bears the evocative title *[Child-birth, or, The Happy Delivery of Women](http://books.google.com/books?id=fPk1AQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Child-birth,+or,+The+Happy+Delivery+of+Women%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FtX3U7r7FsfnoAT9rYCoDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Child-birth%2C%20or%2C%20The%20Happy%20Delivery%20of%20Women%22&f=false)*. The implication here seems to be that the delivery is of women from the burden and suffering of childbirth.

My question is: When did the notion that a mother delivers her child, as opposed to being delivered of her child, arise?

I had expected the *Oxford English Dictionary* to provide a fairly precise answer. But its handling of the relevant definition of *deliver* is surprisingly limited:

> **3** To disburden (a woman) *of* the fœtus, to bring to childbirth ; in *passive*, to give birth to a child or offspring. Rarely said of beasts. (The active is late and and chiefly in obstetrical use.)
>
> *c* **1325** *Metr. Hom.* 63 For than com tim Mari mild Suld be deliuerd of hir child. ... **1480** CAXTON *Chron Eng.* lxxi. 53 Tyme come that she should be delyuered and bere a child. **1484** —*Fables of Æsop* 1. ix,  *A bytche which wolde lyttre and be delyured of her lytyl dogges. **1568** TILNEY *Disc. Mariage* C viii, To have thy wyfe with childe safely delyvered. **1611** SHAKS. *Wint. T.* II. ii. 25 She is, something before her time, deliuer'd. **1685** COOKE *Marrow of Chirurg.* III. I. i. (ed. 4) 168 The third time they sent and begged I would deliver her. **1754–64** SMELLIE *Midwif*. I. Introd. 70 A better method of delivering in laborious and preternatural cases. **1805** *Med. Jrnl.* XIV. 521 By making an incision in the urethra..the patient might be delivered. *c* **1850** *Arab. Nts.* (Rtldg.) 448 The queen..was in due time safely delivered of a prince.

From the OED's treatment of *deliver* definition 3, it appears that the notion of the mother as deliverer came surprisingly late in history. Does anyone know how late?

Comment: This is only a guess, but I wonder if mother-as-deliverer arose due to drift in the meaning of "deliver". I don't think any modern speaker would use "deliver" to mean "disburden" or "liberate" these days, as the "carry" and "hand over" usages have taken over. If "deliver a baby" was already a phrase in the collective vocabulary, it might make sense for the exact sense of who is doing the delivering to change along with the meaning of the word "deliver".

Comment: Mother has *always* delivered her baby, at least until people started helping her and claimed credit for themselves. No one "delivers" from another's womb but only assists in the process. (Julius, you did *everything* different, of course.)

Comment: related [Why use "of" in the phrase: "Delivered of a baby"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120108/why-use-of-in-the-phrase-delivered-of-a-baby)

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delivered+a+child%2Cdelivered+of+a+child&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelivered%20a%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdelivered%20of%20a%20child%3B%2Cc0) seems to say that the transition happened in the first half of the 20th century, when *"delivered a child"* starts overtaking *"delivered of a child"*. There are uses of *"delivered a child"* before that, but they're nearly all written by doctors or midwives.

Comment: @Blckknght Have you considered posting this as an answer? I think you may well be one to something here.

Answer (score 2):

The OED recognises both uses of the verb 'deliver', under their meaning 3.

In both cases, and fundamental to the meaning of 'deliver', is the idea of freeing and releasing. Note that they refer to the second (or b) as the passive.

*a. To disburden (a woman) of the fœtus, to bring to childbirth; in pass., to give birth to a child or offspring. Rarely said of beasts. (The active is late and chiefly in obstetrical use.)
†b.pass. Of the offspring: To be brought forth (lit. and fig.). Obs.*

This has been an excellent question.

It is certainly still current usage, in my experience in Britain, and at least in print, to speak of the mother as the one who has been 'delivered'. ('She was delivered of a nine-pound baby son'.)  But you also see 'the mid-wife assisted in the delivery of a baby girl'. Indeed it not uncommon I believe to speak of the doctor or mid-wife as the one who delivers. It now seems clear that the doctor can both deliver a mother (from the rigours of childbirth), and a child (into the world)

In answer to the question as to when the mother is first spoken of as the 'deliverer' as opposed to the 'delivered', the first OED reference is from 1581.

*1581  G. Pettie tr. S. Guazzo Ciuile Conuersat. (1586) i. 12   All beastes so soone as they are delivered from their dam get upon their feete.*

There are also a couple of references from Shakespeare *circa* 1609.

**Edit 4/July/2020** Reviewing this matter again after six years I believe @Peter Shor summarises the position succinctly in his comment thus:

> If you search Google books for "delivered a child", in the 19th
> century, it's always a doctor or a midwife delivering the child. In
> the early 20th century, you see that some mothers have started
> delivering their own children. But in the 19th century, it's doctors
> either delivering a child of a woman, or delivering a woman of a
> child.

I now believe that @Blckknght made a pertinent contribution when he said:

> This is only a guess, but I wonder if mother-as-deliverer arose due to
> drift in the meaning of "deliver". I don't think any modern speaker
> would use "deliver" to mean "disburden" or "liberate" these days, as
> the "carry" and "hand over" usages have taken over. If "deliver a
> baby" was already a phrase in the collective vocabulary, it might make
> sense for the exact sense of who is doing the delivering to change
> along with the meaning of the word "deliver".

There has clearly, across the centuries been a drift in the meaning of "deliver". Though to me it seems that the two meanings of deliver - a) to liberate someone of something and b) to hand over something to someone, have co-existed across time. There is an OED example of b as early as the thirteenth century.

**Thanks to Peter's succinct summary therefore:**

a)In the 19th century, it's always a doctor or a midwife delivering the child.
b)In the early 20th century, you see that some mothers have started
delivering their own children.
c) But in the 19th century, it's doctors either delivering a child of a woman, or delivering a woman of a child.

Added to this is the additional curiosity that so far as the animal kingdom is concerned, mothers were apparently delivering offspring as long ago as 1581.

*1581 G. Pettie tr. S. Guazzo Ciuile Conuersat. (1586) i. 12 All beastes so soone as they are delivered from their dam get upon their feete.*

Comment: I'm not convinced by your citation. If a baby animal *"was delivered"*, it doesn't mean that the mother delivered it. In this case, it would be *"by their dam"* and not *"from their dam"* if the mother was the agent.

Comment: @PeterShor Not having been around in 1581, I wouldn't know whether in those days people would have said *by their dam* or *from their dam*, and what the significance of each preposition was. What does seem clear is that the thing spoken of as being delivered was the offspring.

Comment: I thought the OP's question was: when did *mothers* start delivering babies as opposed to *doctors* or *midwives* delivering babies. But  rereading, I think I may have misunderstood the question; I can't tell exactly what the OP is asking, and you are certainly answering one of the possible questions.

Comment: @PeterShor The title to the question asks when the mother first becomes the deliverer, as opposed to (the one that is delivered). My answer is 'from about 1581'. And in modern parlance a mother is both 'the deliverer' and 'the delivered'. This thread has clarified a vague confusion I had always had as to why we sometimes say 'Nancy was delivered of a baby girl', and other times 'Nancy delivered a baby girl'. Both are apparently correct (according to the OED).

Comment: And then in the body of the question, the OP asks *"when did the notion that a mother delivers her child, as opposed to being delivered **of** her child, arise?"* Two different questions.

Comment: @PeterShor It is the same question isn't it?

Comment: No, there are two questions here. The mother appears to have started out as the object of the verb *deliver*. The two questions are: (a) when did the baby become acceptable as the object of the verb *deliver*? (b) when did the mother become acceptable as the subject of the verb *deliver*? I think there are several centuries difference between the answers (ca 1580 vs. ca 1900).

Comment: @PeterShor So between 1580 and 1900 who was the subject of the verb deliver? Do you hold to the view that between those dates the mother was not the deliverer because of the 1581 extract referring to 'delivery *from* the dam, rather than *by* the dam.

Comment: If you search Google books for *"delivered a child"*, in the 19th century, it's always a doctor or a midwife delivering the child. In the early 20th century, you see that some mothers have started delivering their own children. But in the 19th century, it's doctors either *delivering a child of a woman,* or *delivering a woman of a child.*

Comment: @PeterShor In my response I think I did say that doctors and midwives also *deliver* babies. However I am now clear as to your point. But deciding on the implied subject of these sentences is altogether a different matter, to that of the object. The two issues are clearly centuries apart.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't know if you remember this little discussion we had in 2014? Reviewing it again, I feel sure that Blckknght's comment, immediately under the OP's question probably gets as close to striking the nail on the head as any. There has clearly, across the centuries been a drift in the meaning of "deliver". Though to me it seems that the two meanings of *deliver* - a) to liberate someone of something and b) to hand over something to someone, have co-existed across time. There is an OED example of b as early as the thirteenth century.

Answer (score 0):

According to Etynomline, *[deliver](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Deliver&searchmode=none)* with the meaning you are referring to was first attested around 1300.: ( actually confirming OED reference).

> - **Childbirth sense in English, "to bring (a woman) to childbirth," is from c.1300**. Sense of "hand over, give, give up, yield" is c.1300. in English, which brings it in opposition to its root.

while  [delivery](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Deliver&searchmode=none)(n.) :

> - early 15c., "action of handing over to another," from Anglo-French delivrée, noun use of fem. past participle of Old French délivrer (see deliver). **Childbirth sense is attested from 1570s**. Of speech, from 1580s. Of a blow, throw of a ball, etc., from 1702.

Answer (score 0):

The mother is the "deliverer." The baby is the "delieveree."

Because the mother "delivers" the baby when giving birth.

Comment: Before the 20th century, the doctor or midwife ***delivered*** the baby. The mother ***gave birth to*** the baby. And the baby was *delivered*  or was *born*, depending on your point of view. Some time in the late 19th or early 20th century, people started misusing the word *"deliver"* for *"gave birth to"*, and that is how it came to have its current meaning.

Comment: @PeterShor But in the 1581 example, the *beastes delivered from their dam*, were not usually cared for by doctors or midwives, I trust. So, who, in a state of nature (which Hobbes depicted as *solitary, poor, nasty, brutish and short*, did the author have in mind as doing the delivering?  I am intrigued to know how you know that the notion of mothers "delivering" entered the language by way of a mistake in the late 19th century.